# Converting discrete values into real values in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a numpy array with discrete values. I used numpy.digitize() function to get these discrete values from continuous values. Now I want to convert these discrete values back to the original continuous values. Is there a function in python which can help me doing that?  A sample code has been added below:

```
        A = [437.479, 438.536, 440.026,............,471.161]
        bins = numpy.linspace(numpy.amin(A),numpy.amax(A),255) 
        discretized_A = numpy.digitize(A, bins) 
        discretized_A = [1,8,18,................,237]
```

As you see here I had a vector of real values, I used digitize function to project that vector in space of min to max of A with 255 equal spacing values. So i got the end result as discretized_A. Now I want to reverse engineer the steps and get my original real values.

Comment: Add a sample case - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve?

Comment: @Divakar Thanks for your suggestion.  I have added the code and some explanation. Hope it makes the question clear. Would be great if you could help :)